# why manual Chip select in SPI not functioning efr32fg14

Tags: embedded

Hello i am using efr32fg14 starter kit with manual shown bellow.
my CS in SPI is PC9 asshown in the diagram bellow.
When i tried to make it manual,I wrote GPIO PC9  be high before transmission then during transmission GPIO PC9 is low and after SPI commans i put GPIO PC9be high again.
In the SCOPE i get total zero.
The full code is attached bellow.
Where did i go wrong?
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/user-guides/ug318-brd4257b-user-guide.pdf

[image]

```
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_usart.h"

#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE   4
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE   TX_BUFFER_SIZE

uint8_t com1[TX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x03,0x0F,0xFF,0xF0};


uint8_t RxBuffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE];

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Initialize USART1
 *****************************************************************************/
void initUSART1 (void)
{
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART1, true);

  // Configure GPIO mode
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 8, gpioModePushPull, 0); // US1_CLK is push pull
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 9, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_CS is push pull
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 6, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_TX (MOSI) is push pull
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 7, gpioModeInput, 1);    // US1_RX (MISO) is input
 // GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 0, gpioModePushPull, 1); //delay


  // Start with default config, then modify as necessary
  USART_InitSync_TypeDef config = USART_INITSYNC_DEFAULT;
  config.master       = true;            // master mode
  config.baudrate     = 1000000;         // CLK freq is 1 MHz
  config.autoCsEnable = false;            // CS pin controlled by hardware, not firmware
  config.clockMode    = usartClockMode1; // clock idle low, sample on rising/first edge
  config.msbf         = true;            // send MSB first
  config.enable       = usartDisable;    // Make sure to keep USART disabled until it's all set up
  USART_InitSync(USART1, &config);

  // Set USART pin locations
  USART1->ROUTELOC0 = (USART_ROUTELOC0_CLKLOC_LOC11) | // US1_CLK       on location 11 = PC8 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 8
                      (USART_ROUTELOC0_CSLOC_LOC11)  | // US1_CS        on location 11 = PC9 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 10
                      (USART_ROUTELOC0_TXLOC_LOC11)  | // US1_TX (MOSI) on location 11 = PC6 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 4
                      (USART_ROUTELOC0_RXLOC_LOC11);   // US1_RX (MISO) on location 11 = PC7 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 6

  // Enable USART pins
  USART1->ROUTEPEN = USART_ROUTEPEN_CLKPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_CSPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_TXPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_RXPEN;

  // Enable USART1
  USART_Enable(USART1, usartEnable);
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Main function
 *****************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
  uint32_t i;

  // Initialize chip
  CHIP_Init();

  // Initialize USART1 as SPI slave
  initUSART1();
  GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortC,9);
  for(i=0;i<115;i++)//delay
          {
           GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortA,5);
           GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortA,5);
           }
  while(1)
  {
     GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortC,9);
            USART_SpiTransfer(USART1,com1[0]);
            USART_SpiTransfer(USART1,com1[1]);
            USART_SpiTransfer(USART1,com1[2]);
            USART_SpiTransfer(USART1,com1[3]);
          GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortC,9);
          for(i=0;i<115;i++)//delay
          {
           GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortA,5);
           GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortA,5);
           }
  } 
}
```

Comment: But if the CS is GPIO, does the code configure it for alternate use, like it does for CS and all the other pins with the pin routing thing?

Comment: SPI is much easier to troubleshoot with a waveform and a logic analyzer, logic analyzers are cheap now

Comment: The SPI CS i.e. PC9 is also a UART1 CS pin. Maybe this is causing the problem. If you have a logic Analysis, connect it and see if it goes HIGH as you ask it to but then goes low because you are also using UART1. Also, if you use USART0, you might avoid this conflict.

Comment: Hello Justme,I desabled it so i can control it manualy.
before this change the PC9 worked great .every SPI start it got lowered and at the end it got high again(i checked with scope)
But when i dissabled and tried to get it low and high  manually it just showed me 0 the whole time.What could cause that?